# How can I save an array of checkboxes in a wordpress widget?

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, widget

I've created a widget and I need to allow the user to select from a series of options. The options are books coming from another table in the database.

I'm trying to use code like this:

```
<input type="text" name="<?PHP $this->get_field_name("books[]"); ?>">
```

However this fails when trying to save. Is it even possible to pass an array of options like this and save them? If not, what would be an alternative solution. I could pass values like this:

```
book1
book2
book3
```

If I do this I would have to have a loop in the update method go through all the books in the database to determine what is checked and what isn't? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question is about checkboxes, but your html is rendering a text box. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

First, store the options and pick them as an array:

```
$options = get_option("pluginName_books");

update_option("pluginName_books",$_REQUEST['books']);
```

Use this as the field in your form:

```
<input type="text" name="books[]" value="the_value">
```

or to do it as a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<?PHP $this->get_field_name("books[]"); ?>">
```

Comment: This is what I needed. I set the name of the checkboxes to books[] then just used the update_option function in the update method of the wp_widget class. Works perfectly. I didn't consider using the options as an additional storage mechanism. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was in deed helpful, but I would like to mention that in most cases, it would be enaught to implode( ',', $_REQUEST['books']) and save it with instance of the plugin. On widget form on frontend display, you can explode( ',', $instance['book'] ); - thus it isn't always necessary to save values into options table

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. I solved it by attaching the array part of my name tag outside of my get_field_name call:

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'breakpoints' ); ?>[]"
```